# ruby datamapper - how to save a query

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

I have a model user with name,age,gender as attributes. a user can query with the following criteria age and gender. how to save this query. one way would be to convert it as age => between age1 and age2 and gender => 'M' and save this query in a table with user id and query string and a name for the query. 
what would be good way to do this..if i have to use this query to find out who else would fit in this role in future(say somebody else would have saved a query and i need to find whose queries would I fit in based on my age and gender  ..basically i need to be able to match my age and gender to the saved query/ selection criteria)
I am using sinatra for the model

thanks

Comment: is this something you want to do for only this particular case or for several different tables and fields?

Comment: I have tried to make the model simple...but in reality the user is associated with other table/model..so the query could be much complex(based on the field in the other tables as well not just age and gender).

Answer (score 0):

I like DataMapper, but there are cases when it's better to just write some SQL to solve your problem and then let DataMapper do part of the work for you. I usually use DataMapper for the relatively simple queries and resort to good old SQL when things get more complicated.

In your case, the SQL command would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE (want_age_min IS NULL OR age >= want_age_min)
AND (want_age max IS NULL OR age <= want_age_max)
AND (want_sex IS NULL OR want_sex = my_sex)
```

You're selecting from all people already enrolled in the system, and you're adding one criterion for each relevant attribute. The result will be people who either don't care about minimum age (want_age_min is null) or the minimum age is less than or equal to the candidate's age. And the same for all attributes.

This way, the "saved query" is just a row with columns specifying conditions. Then you can actually use this one query for all cases.

Comment: but can you built a query to see if you would fit into the query of all the users in the system..

Comment: hm... you mean like in a dating site? you fill a form and want to show which users would be interested in you?